# Put an ID as the value of a variable and that corresponds to the value of that id in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following code:

```
export const MOCK_CONTROLESTADOMES: ControlEstadoMes[] = [
{ id: 0, mes: "Enero", anyo: 2017, bloqueado: true },
{ id: 1, mes: "Febrero", anyo: 2017, bloqueado: true },
{ id: 2, mes: "Marzo", anyo: 2017, bloqueado: true },
{ id: 3, mes: "Abril", anyo: 2017, bloqueado: true },
{ id: 4, mes: "Mayo", anyo: 2017, bloqueado: true },
{ id: 5, mes: "Junio", anyo: 2017, bloqueado: true },
{ id: 6, mes: "Julio", anyo: 2017, bloqueado: true },
{ id: 7, mes: "Agosto", anyo: 2017, bloqueado: true },
{ id: 8, mes: "Septiembre", anyo: 2017, bloqueado: true },
{ id: 9, mes: "Octubre", anyo: 2017, bloqueado: true },
{ id: 10, mes: "Noviembre", anyo: 2017, bloqueado: true },
{ id: 11, mes: "Diciembre", anyo: 2017, bloqueado: true },
{ id: 12, mes: "Enero", anyo: 2018, bloqueado: true },
{ id: 13, mes: "Febrero", anyo: 2018, bloqueado: true },
{ id: 14, mes: "Marzo", anyo: 2018, bloqueado: true },
{ id: 15, mes: "Abril", anyo: 2018, bloqueado: false },
{ id: 16, mes: "Mayo", anyo: 2018, bloqueado: false },
{ id: 17, mes: "Junio", anyo: 2018, bloqueado: false },
{ id: 18, mes: "Julio", anyo: 2018, bloqueado: false },
{ id: 19, mes: "Agosto", anyo: 2018, bloqueado: false },
{ id: 20, mes: "Septiembre", anyo: 2018, bloqueado: false },
{ id: 21, mes: "Octubre", anyo: 2018, bloqueado: false },
{ id: 22, mes: "Noviembre", anyo: 2018, bloqueado: false },
{ id: 23, mes: "Diciembre", anyo: 2018, bloqueado: false }
```

]

And this:

```
export class Meses {
id: number;
mes: string;
```

}

What I need is to get the value of the month from the Months class through the class id Months, but passing this ID in the month value of ControlEstadoMes [].

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I tried to put mes: id.Meses, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can use a find on an array. Find will return the object in the array filtering where the month.id is equal to the id you're trying to find.

`let id = 2;
let month =  MOCK_CONTROLESTADOMES.find(month => month.id == id);
// month = { id: 2, mes: "Marzo", anyo: 2017, bloqueado: true }`

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. What I needed was that by passing it an id number of the MESES class, I took out the value of the string from that id:

Comment: So you want to pass an ID into the `Meses` class and then the class is populated with the correct month data? Or are talking about converting a `ControlEstadoMes` object to a `Meses` object?